# Indesign: add line break after first two words in batch

Tags: adobe-indesign, batch-processing, grep

I am looking to insert a line break after two words for a large document on multiple paragraphs. I am using find/change to search for ^w which inserts a line break after one space, what would be the syntax to search for 2 spaces.

So I need the first two words of a paragraph with a forced line break inserted after those 2 words.

For example:
Dan Brown ***(line break)***
Author, Fortress, Da Vinci Code etc.

Thanks in advance

Kev

Answer (score 1):

Use this Grep query, which can probably be improved and explained if needed. If you're reusing this multiple times, I suggest saving this query - see the floppy disk icon thing.

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic thanks. The only thing is when I replace with suggested GREP it starts a new paragraph instead of just inserting a line break.

Comment: (Minor only:) while `\w` matches a *word character*, which apparently works for the OP, you could also use the *not-a-space* set `\S`. That way, you catch everything else that may pop up in a name as well -- think hyphens, apostrophes, the like.

Comment: (Minor #2 ) You can lop off the spaces at the end by moving the final `\s` outside the closing parenthesis.